# std::bind not working with 1 parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, std

Ran into a bit of an issue with `std::bind` when adding a placeholder
My code is kind of big so I'll just stick to the essentials

```
#define GETFUNC(a) (std::bind(&app::a, this, std::placeholders::_1))
class button{
button(<other parameters here>, std::function<void(int)>) { ... }
..
std::function<void(int)> onhover;
..
};

class app{
app(){
elements.push_back(buttonPtr( new button(<other parameters>, GETFUNC(onHover) );
..
typedef std::unique_ptr<button> buttonPtr;
std::vector<buttonPtr> elements;
..
void onHover(int i) {}
}
```

That bit of code fails at `std::bind` ( that much I got from the [error log](http://pastebin.com/htD8CTKW) )
but works if I change:

- all `std::function<void(int)>` to `std::function<void()>`
- `onHover(int i)` to `onHover()`
- `std::bind(&app::a, this, std::placeholders::_1)` to `std::bind(&app::a, this)`

Any thoughts on why this happens and how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you describe what you are trying to do in plain english? What is `window`? Does it have a `onHover` member? What is the type? --Also, macros make everything harder to read and debug, consider expanding the macro manually and read how it should look

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: trying to add some callbacks to my buttons(on hover, onclick etc)

Comment: Isn't there a mismatch between the class's name (`app`) and the class name used in the macro (`window`)?

Comment: @user1233963: please address the other questions, in particular what `window` is. (And I was expecting a slightly more lengthy explanation, like adding a callback to the object that that will execute X)

Comment: @Angew: I changed the name of the class when I posted the question but forgot to change the one in the macro. Sorry about the confusion

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas: app is supposed to be a class that manages a window(a real application window, not another class [just to be clear]). app also manages events for the buttons like onHover (for now). It has an event loop and when certain conditions are met it should call the proper function with and ID as a parameter (hence the int I'm trying to add )

Comment: Compiles as written (after removing the pseudocode) on VS2010. Possible gcc issue? Have you tried only the minimal code?

Comment: @AndreiTita: minimal code does work

Comment: @user1233963 : Unless you can demonstrate (minimal) code that _doesn't_ work, I don't know how anyone here can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's working fine. Check this and look for differences to your code.

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>


struct app
{
  std::function<void (int)>
  get_func ()
  {
    return std::bind (&app::on_hover, this, std::placeholders::_1);
  }

  void on_hover (int v)
  {
    std::cout << "it works: " << v << std::endl;
  }
};

int
main ()
{
  app a;

  auto f = a.get_func ();
  f (5);
}
```

Comment: Tracked the problem down. I was binding a method of a class that I inherited from which had no parameters. Sorry for taking up your time